# AngularJS $scope.$apply() Dilemma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using AngularJS with Firebase Realtime Database to create a simple list app that syncs across devices. The web client code can be found below.

The problem is that I need to use the $scope.$apply function in my Firebase `on('val')` callback because this callback is executed from outside of AngularJS and without it, the bindings aren't updated. However, when the user enters a new list item and clicks the Add button, I'm seeing a `angular.js:12520 Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`. I assume that this happens because I'm calling the `$digest()` method when I'm already inside a `$digest()`.

So how can I achieve what I'm trying to do? i.e. use the explicit `$digest()` method when the callback is triggered outside of AngularJS and do not use it otherwise.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var config = {
                apiKey: "XXX",
                authDomain: "XXX",
                databaseURL: "XXX",
                storageBucket: "XXX",
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                var database = firebase.database();
                database.ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $scope.items = [];
                        var result = snapshot.val();
                        for(var key in result) {
                            var listItem = result[key];
                            $scope.items.push(listItem);
                        }
                    });
                });
                $scope.addItem = function () {
                    database.ref().push().set($scope.addMe);
                }
            });
        </script>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in items">{{x}}</li>
            </ul>
            <input ng-model="addMe">
            <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIX 1 -**

Use

```
$timeout(function(){ 
  $scope.$apply()
  ... write your code here 
},0)
```

It will be triggered when the digest cycle is completed.

**FIX 2 -**

`$scope.$$phase` will return true if the digest cycle is running else false, but it will not be useful in your case as it doesn't provide any callback function.

**Also its not recommended to use**

Comment: Does this work because the timeout callback is executed outside of the AngularJS scope therefore ensuring that the call to $apply() does not throw the error? If so, it seems like a little bit of a hack. Is this the recommended approach in situations like this? Are there any design patterns I could adopt to prevent the need for this?

Comment: No, its not a hack.
There are minimum 2 digest cycles running during the execution of controller.One is the normal one, second digest cycle runs to ensure if there is any $timeout or not?
So if we write anything in $timeout, it makes sure that it runs after the execution of first digest cycle.
So its a perfect approach according to me if we want to get rid of the above conflict.